# How to play a Vimeo video in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, vimeo

I've tried to search to web, but I couldn't find a topic not older than 1 year regarding this problem, therefore;

How can I play a Vimeo video in an iOS App?

**EDIT1:** When using [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8308372/617413) I'm sometimes getting this HTTP response from Vimeo

[image]

Why?

Comment: You mean, without using a `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 9):

This is my way of play a Vimeo video inside a app.

I am using iFrame to load Vimeo video inside my app.

follow this steps and you will too.

create a uiwebview and connect it to your .h file. Mine is _webView.

Add this method to your .m file.

```
-(void)embedVimeo{

NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.vimeo.com/embed/rOPI5LDo7mg\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];

[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
}
```

I am using the embedded code in Vimeo video. (I hope you know what it is)

call this method inside your viewdidload

```
[self embedVimeo];
```

Run the app and you will see the video in your view. This way is perfectly working for me and i think this will help for your too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [YTVimeoExtractor](https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor), works fine for me.

Comment: Is this future proof?

Comment: is anything future proof?

Comment: No it is not future proof, nor supported in any way by Vimeo.

Comment: The project is still maintained and new features are coming. You can go ahead and use it :)

Comment: Not to be a downer, but I'm certain this isn't allowed in the Vimeo ToS :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
NSString *htmlStringToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\%%22%%20width=\%%22%0.0f\%%22%%20height=\%%22%0.0f\%%22%%20frameborder=\%%230\%%22", videoID];
        [aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlStringToLoad]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it seems that this only works with some videos? For my video I get this message "This video can't be played with your setup" whereas other videoes are working fine (like this http://vimeo.com/32424117). Why?

Comment: Do I need a Vimeo Plus account?

Comment: I don't know really, in YouTube I know there is some videos that is private videos or restricted to some regions, therefore they cannot be embedded. Anyway,try to work with Vimeo API(for iOS), and fetch the error received from server.

Comment: Downvoted this ``UIWebView`` solution, because it's way better to use ``MPMoviePlayerController`` instead of the large webkit.

Comment: @ChristianBeer sure, but that is not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

Please try [this](https://github.com/tannauit/PlayVimeo),
It works for me, just some lines of code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    vimeoHelper = [[VimeoHelper alloc] init];
    [vimeoHelper getVimeoRedirectUrlWithUrl:@"http://vimeo.com/52760742" delegate:(id)self];
}

- (void)finishedGetVimeoURL:(NSString *)url
{
    _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self presentViewController:_moviePlayerController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is this allowed by Vimeo ToS? I know YouTube doesn't allow direct parsing of video files.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code:

```
NSString *embedSr = @"<iframe width=\"304\"height=\"350\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/... \" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

[[self WebView] loadHTMLString:embedSr baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code the it will work fine

```
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] ;
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendString:@"<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/84403700?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"1024\" height=\"768\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];


[viewWeb loadHTMLString:html baseURL:urlMovie];
```

Comment: What is `urlMovie` supposed to be set as? You don't show that definition in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the [universal player](http://vimeo.com/blog:334), it is successful in device with iOS 5, but failed in iOS 4.2 with iPhone 3G. I don't know why. [Here's](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player) the link to embed it.

Or you can embed manually from the Vimeo site, click embed, and configure the config as you wish.