# Nothing displayed when trying to run a Vimeo video iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo

I am trying to run a vimeo video in my app, and the method that makes the most sense to me is the method from this example [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918011/4856759 ].

So I have attempted to recreate this method in swift with my own vimeo link, but all I get is a blank screen.

As far as I can tell I have created the relevant string, converted it an NSString and loaded it using the loadHTMLString method - what am I missing?

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var embedHTML = "<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.vimeo.com/113067409" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"

    var html: NSString = NSString(string: embedHTML)

    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: are you sure the vimeo link is valid?? I m getting cannot find the page..

Comment: Woops, you are right. I've edited the link, but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your  link is valid, but the way you are embedding the HTML for vimeo is not correct and also you have to set the base url to* `"http://"`  *instead of nil.*

**Here is working code:-**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var embedHTML="<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/113067409?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"1024\" height=\"768\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>";

        webView.delegate = self
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://")!
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML as String, baseURL:url )
}
```